# MVC 5 JQuery bundles : client-side validation in trouble

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I'm trying to understand why I'm encountered several troubles with my client-side validation. If I'm bundling like that :

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobstrusive.min.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"));
```

client-side validation doesn't work.

If I'm bundling like that :

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"));
```

everything is fine.
If I remove any file in the first configuration, it doesn't work.

Do you have an explanation?

Comment: Confused, which method does not work?  At first glance they read the same.

Comment: Yes, I'm also confused, that's the problem. I'm unable to make client-side working if I change anything in the second part...

Comment: So both work right now, what do you WANT to change?  know that `Web.Optimization` will remove `min` files depending on your build configuration.

Comment: I would like to understand, that's all, for me there is no reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like all the libraries are required for the validation you are attempting to perform;

1. jQuery is required as a base library and all your validation libraries have this dependancy
2. jQuery.validation is a jQuery plug-in for specifying validation through HTML attributes
3. jQuery.unobtrusive-ajax is not for validation but is a plug-in for specifying ajax configuration through HTML attributes.

While it is unlikely `unobtrusive-ajax` is required for validation; in your case you may be implementing some custom validation that takes advantage of functionality that this plug-in exposes.

The other topic that might be of influence here is the way MVC deals with [Bundling and Minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification), where if `debug` is set to true `min.js` files are removed from the bundle.